# Timestamp is generated for next record, as opposed to current record

Tags: ms-access, timestamp

I have a slight issue with MS-Access, which is as follows.

I have a table with a Timestamp column (the format of the field is `Date/Time`, the default value is `Now()`). The issue is that whenever I create a new record, the timestamp is set for the next record I am going to create, as opposed to the record I am creating.

This means that I create record 50, and the Timestamp is set for record 51. If I come back a week later, and create record 51, the Timestamp for record 51 will be a week out, and the timestamp will be set for record 52, which I will be creating at some point in the future.

You can re-create the problem by firing up MS-Access, creating a new table with a couple of fields, one of which is Date/Time and setting the Default Value of this field to `Now()`.

Is this by design, or am I doing something dumb? If it is by design, how can I implement the type of Timestamp that I want (one where the Date/Time is set as the record is created) in MS-Access? If I am doing something dumb, what exactly am I doing?

Edit: Below is a screenshot of a newly created Access table:

[image: initial]

I add some text to record one, the Timestamp gets set for record two:

[image: Second]

I allow some time to pass, put some data into record two, and the timestamp doesn't change, and now record three has a timestamp:

[image: Third]

If I close and open the table, the Timestamp for the (New) record gets updated to whenever I opened the table:

[image: Then]

I allow some time to pass, update the record and the Timestamp stays at the time I opened the table:

[image: Finally]

Comment: This is not my experience. When I close the table and re-open, I get a new time stamp. When I refresh I get a new timestamp even if I leave the table sitting open.

Comment: Under the conditions you describe, the TimeStamp is generated when you type the first character into the new record you are creating, if you are using the form to do so. If you are creating the records programmatically, the Timestamp will be created at the moment you generate the new record. Some Access users interpret the new record (marked with an asterisk * in the form) as an actual record, when in fact it's not a record at all until a character is typed into one of the fields, at which time the record is actually generated, and a new "placeholder" item (*) is displayed in the form.

Comment: If you have some code, now would be a good time to post it, as we can probably look at the code and tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't have any code but I have updated the question with Screenshots

Comment: You are editing a table, which you should only be doing as the highly knowledgeable creator of the system :) Hit the refresh button if you are away for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is already revealed in the comments, this problem comes from editing in the table with Now() set as the Default for your TimeStamp field.

I suggest you create a form instead of editing in the table. If you want it to look similar just use a datasheet form. Then on the Form's BeforeUpdate event put code in like this:

```
Me!TimeStamp = Now()
```

As a side note, I wouldn't use TimeStamp as a field name. Some RDBMS such as SQL Server have a data type called TimeStamp. It's best to avoid using field names that are data types or reserved words. Moving an Access database to SQL Server is extremely common and you could have problems when you try to do it.

Instead, I would create two fields. One called DateTimeEntered and another called DateTimeModified. I consider these two fields to be necessary in pretty much every table I make. If you ever want to do any kind of synchronization of records you'll wish you had at least a DateTimeModified field.